# Move value from line to another line?

Tags: mysql, sql

[image]

I have a table like `figure (1)`. 10000 is the moneyStock of 12 months of all products. 5000 is the moneyStock of 12 months of product 384. Now I like to get money, moneyStock and total of product 384 like `figure (3)`. How to do it?
Figure (2) is what I tried:

```
SELECT siire_code, zaiko_code, month_str, money
FROM test
WHERE siire_code = 384 OR (siire_code = 560 AND zaiko_code = 384)
GROUP BY month_str, zaiko_code
```

Note: `560` is the id for moneyStock of all months of all products.

**Update:** Table struture added.

[image]

Comment: Despite the pretty diagram, I've no clue what you're after.  Are figures 1 and 2 the same table or different tables? What are the tables (or is the table) called? If you're trying to get totals, why haven't you got a SUM in your SQL?  What do you think is going to happen when `zaiko_code` is NULL (or blank, or whatever).  What are the types of the columns?

Comment: Figure (1) is the original table. Figure (3) is what I want (the destination). Figure (2) is what I've tried so far. Table structure added.

Comment: I admire your foresight in allowing for 43 digits in the years portion of the month string, but you will run into difficulties in Y10K (and the universe will have ended a fair while before you run out of digits for the years).  You might do better to use CHAR(6) for the month string, too.  It is also unorthodox to use a string to store money values; numbers should be stored in columns with an appropriate numeric type.

Comment: I'm sorry this table structure is just a quick sample. I think it doesn't affect to queries too much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select a.month_str,a.money,ifnull(b.moneyStock,0) moneyStock, 
       a.money+ifnull(b.moneyStock,0) total
from (select siire_code code,month_str, sum(money) money
        from yourtable
        where siire_code = 384
        group by siire_code,month_str)a 
left outer join 
        (select zaiko_code code, month_str, sum(money) moneyStock
        from yourtable
        where siire_code =560 
        and zaiko_code =384
        group by zaiko_code, month_str) b
on (a.code = b.code
and a.month_str = b.month_str)
```

see the [SQLFiddle Demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9528b/3)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
  s.month_str,
  s.money,
  IFNULL(z.money, 0) 'moneyStock',
  (IFNULL(z.money, 0) + s.money) 'total'
FROM
  Source s
LEFT JOIN
    Source z
  ON
      s.siire_code = z.zaiko_code
    AND
      s.month_str = z.month_str
    AND
      z.siire_code = 560
WHERE
  s.siire_code = 384
```

Working **[DEMO!](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0a43b/19)**

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
SELECT month_str, sum(one_t.money), sum(other_t.money), sum(all_t.money)
FROM   test
       LEFT JOIN test one_t
         ON test.siire_code = one_t.siire_code
       LEFT JOIN test other_t
         ON test.siire_code = other_t.zaiko_code
       LEFT JOIN test all_t
         ON test.siire_code = all_t.siire_code
            OR test.siire_coe = one_t.zaiko_code
WHERE  siire_code = 384
       OR (siire_code = 560
           AND zaiko_code = 384)
GROUP  BY month_str
```